# Integer-valued power sums

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

Suppose I have a positive number $d \in \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of numbers $a_n \in [0,d]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with the following properties 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i^r \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \leq d \ .
$$

> > Does it follow that only finitely many of the $a_i$ are non-zero?

Note that it does not follow that $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ as the sequence $a_1 = 2 + \sqrt{2}$, $a_2 = 2 - \sqrt{2}$, $a_k = 0$ for $k > 2$ with $d=4$ shows. This sequence also shows that the power sums can be unbounded.

Comment: $a_2$ is not in $[0,d]$ in your example.

Comment: Whoopsy daisy. Fixed.

Comment: What is the sense of $\sum a_i\leqslant d$ condition? It works for $d=\sum a_i$.

Comment: I guess it just means $(a_i)\in\ell^1$.

Comment: Yep. It's late over here. I will blame the bad marks for style on that.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think if $d=1$ then there can be a single $i$ such that $a_i = 1$ and the rest are zero. I'm trying to think of how to normalize the statement so that the case for all $d$ generalizes from the case for $d=1$.

Comment: Frankly I don't see why Fan Zheng's proof (now deleted) fails. Forget all the zero $a_i$s a they have no effect.  Consider $\prod_i (1+a_i)$. Since $\sum_i a_i^2<\infty$ (given), this product converges if $\sum_i a_i$ converges, which is given.  But all the elementary symmetric functions of the $a_i$ are integers, by Newton's relations, so the product does not converge. What have I missed?

Comment: I think Newton's relations only imply that the elementary symmetric functions are all rational.

Comment: @JeremyRouse : You are quite correct.  That "proof" is false.  Newton's relations only obviously require the $j$-th elementary symmetric function to be an integer multiple of $1/j!$.

Comment: This is exactly where I am mistaken.

Comment: Ok, here's a thought, based on the OP's example (I may be completely wrong here, I'm not an expert).

If we consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, for example, and take $a_0\in K$ that has a countable Galois orbit over $\mathbb{Q}$ (I'm not sure if such $a_0$ exists, as I said, I'm no expert), then we can take $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ to be all the Galois conjugates of $a_0$, which implies $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\in \mathbb Q$ as well as $\sum_{i=}^\infty a_i^r\in\mathbb Q$ as well (the $a_i^r$s are also conjugates). By changing $a_0$- Can we make it so that all sums above are actually in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The Galois orbit of $a_0$ will be a torsor for a Galois group, and Galois groups are profinite so either finite or uncountable; in particular they're never countably infinite. There are also issues with convergence in this approach.

Comment: There is an example where all the $a_{i}$ are nonzero, and $\sum a_{i}^{r}$ is an _algebraic_ integer for all $r \geq 1$.

Comment: What's the example like?

Comment: @JeremyRouse Could you explain how the example works?

Comment: I don't want to keep posting comments on this question, so I'll explain in [chat].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function 
$$
f : z \in \mathbb{C} \longmapsto \sum_{i} \frac{a_i}{1-a_iz}
$$
is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and has integral Taylor coefficients. It follows from a theorem of Borel that such a function must be in $\mathbb{Q}(z)$; see for example Richard Stanley's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6179/does-there-exist-a-meromorphic-function-all-of-whose-taylor-coefficients-are-pri). In particular $f$ has only finitely many poles ; this implies that only finitely many of the $a_i$'s are nonzero.

Comment: It worth mention that the argument of Borel (http://www.archive.org/stream/s2bulletindessci18fran#page/n27/mode/2up) looks to be the same, or at least very similar, as Ilya suggests in his answer to this question

Comment: @js21: Isn't there a condition in the paper by Borel about not having singularities except poles in a disc of some radius? How is that satisfied for your $f$?

Comment: @Ulrich Pennig: Such a condition does not appear in Borel's text. He only assumes that $f$ is meromorphic on a disc of radius $>1$. I agree that the sentence "la fonction $A(x)$ n'a pas d'autres singularites que $p$ poles a l'interieur d'un disque de rayon $\rho'>1$" might be misleading : in this context, it should be translated as "the singularities of $A(x)$ in the disc of radius $0$ are at most poles, and there are at most $p$ of them".

Comment: @js21 That is precisely the sentence I stumbled over. Thank you for the clarification. I will have a closer look at the proof of Borel's theorem.

Answer (score 5):

OK. I've finally got the time to correct my deleted answer. If anyone doesn't like complex analysis, this answer only uses *real* analysis.

Let $f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_nx)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_nx^n$, where $e_n$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial in $(a_n)$. Then as observed in the comments, $e_n\in\mathbb{Z}/n!$, so if infinitely many $a_n>0$, then $e_n\ge1/n!$, which implies $f(x)\ge e^x$, or $\log f(x)\ge x$ for $x>0$. On the other hand, we can pick $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n<1/2$. Then $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \log(1+a_nx)<x/2$. Also $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \log(1+a_nx)=o(x)$, so $\log f(x)\le(1/2+o(1))x$, contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

This is **not** an answer --- but perhaps someone can fill the gap?

Clearly, we have $d>1$. Denote 
$$
  n_r=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^r\in\mathbb N.
$$
Choose some $k$ such that 
$$
  \sum_{i>k}a_i<\frac1{2d}
$$
(all $k$ greater than some $k_0$ fit). Set 
$$
  P(x)=(x-a_1)\dots(x-a_k)=x^k+p_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\dots+p_0.
$$

Now, look at the rows $m_0,\dots,m_{3k}$ of the matrix $M_{k,s}=[n_{s+i+j}]_{0\leq i,j\leq 3k}$ (for some large $s$). We see that for every $i\geq k$ the elements of
$$
  m_i'=m_i+p_{k-1}m_{i-1}+\dots+p_0m_{i-k}
$$
are expressed via the sums of large powers of $a_i$, $i>k$, with bounded coefficients. Thus all elements of $m_i'$ are less than $C_k/(2d)^s$ with some constant $C_k$ depending only on $k$. On the other hand, the entries of $m_0,\dots,m_{k-1}$ do not exceed $\alpha_k kd^{s+k}$ for some constant $\alpha_k$ also depending on $k$ only.

Replacing the $m_i$ with $m_i'$ does not chande $\det M_{s,k}$, so 
$$
  \det M_{s,k}\leq (3k)!\cdot (\alpha_kkd^{s+k})^k\cdot \left(\frac{C_k}{(2d)^s}\right)^{2k}
$$
which tends to $0$ as $s\to\infty$. On the other hand, $\det M_{s,k}$ is integer, so $\det M_{s,k}=0$ for all sufficiently large $s\geq s_k$.

Now I **would like to** say that this yields $(n_r)$ be a linear recurrent sequence from some moment. Ptifully, this is not true in general, but perhaps some argument may fill this?

Notice that if $(n_r)$ were linear recurrent, the rest is easy. Indeed, we may prove inductively (assuming $a_1\geq a_2\geq \dots$) that all nonzero $a_i$ are the roots of its characteristic polynomial, so they are finitely many.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt the arguments of Borel (see the answer by js21) and get a solution without complex analysis?

Comment: Why the implication from vanishing determinant to linear recurrence relation fails? Isn't this Lemma 9 in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/?